# n-ary relations with views

Tags: views

I have a relation type with arity 3. i.e. Book, Publisher and Author. I'm trying to create a view where, given the publisher id as argument, it lists all the other end points of the relation type. I am able to do this for binary relations, but not able to do so for arity > 2. For now, I am doing a relation_query() to accomplish the same.

Comment: I think the relation module is the tool for that (Drupal 7). Check nodeone's series on it: http://dev.nodeone.se/node/970